# How can I correctly format this JSON data from a backpack.tf API request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to use the [backpack.tf](https://backpack.tf/developer) API for a Discord Bot I'm developing. I'm currently attempting the [UserInfo](https://backpack.tf/api/docs/user_info) portion of it. Using my own Steam ID within the API URL results in this output [image]

Essentially, having `users`, then the ID, and finally the actual information I'm trying to use. My code is as follows:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const superagent = require("superagent");
const { apiKey } = require("../db/config.json");
module.exports = {
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Enter in a steam ID!")
        let id = args[0]
        console.log(id)
        let { body } = await superagent
            .get(`https://backpack.tf/api/users/info/v1?steamids=${id}&key=${apiKey}`);
        message.channel.send(
            new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setImage(body.users.id.avatar)
        );
        if (!{ body }) return message.channel.send("Check that ID again!");
    },
    aliases: ["bp"]
}
```

Most of this is just framework, but it's basically making a call to the API through superagent. When it returns, I attempt to use `body.users.id.avatar` to get the avatar of a a user. Instead of doing this, it outputs a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined` error. The API seems to give no errors when it's simply `body.users.id`, but adding another layer to it prompts it to break.

I'd want it to simply give me the result I'm asking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a dynamic property name, `body.users` is an object with key values of actual ids with numbers, there won't be a direct `.id` property, as such `body.users.id` is undefined

the reason body.users.id doesn't give any errors is because its only undefined but you aren't trying to call a property on it, like you do when you call `body.users.id.avatar`

`body.users.id.avatar` => `undefined.avatar`

This should fix it:

```js
body.users[id].avatar
```

An example of how this looks:

```js
const id = "2324389";
const obj = {
  "2324389": 23,
  "1234678": 22,
  "id": 21
};

obj.id
// => 21

obj[id]
// => 23

/* obj[id] is the same as below */

obj["2324389"]
// => 23
```

Also: `if (!{ body })`

this line might give errors, either way it will never be false since its evaluating if the object is truthy which it is, regardless of the properties

If you were trying to error handle with this, it needs to be earlier in the code, and you need to use `.catch` instead, unless the API doesn't throw an error even if ID is invalid